# sqlite select no such column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am making a sql Query I try to find if a similar name already exists into dabs , but its keeping dispatching error saying that no such column David exists , could please help

```
const texts = 'David'
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name LIKE '+texts+';', [], (tx, results)
```

Comment: Your query is `like David`, where David is a column name.  You should pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is, the query that your code produces is :

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name LIKE David;
```

sqlite does consider unquoted `David` as a column name, hence the error you are getting.

You probably want this instead :

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name LIKE 'David';
```

`LIKE` without wildcard on the right side does not really make sense, so that could be either of the following queries, depending if you want exact match or not

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name LIKE '%David%';
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name = 'David';
```

To generate the query, you could use the following code :

```
"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name LIKE '%" + texts + "%';"
"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name = '" + texts + "';"
```